# Upload in VB.Net using HttpClient for WEB API

Tags: vb.net

I would like to upload a file to vendor WEB API using HttpClient in VB.NET via HTTPS.
I have this code to upload a file:

```
Dim httpclient As WebClient
Dim _cookieStore As Cookie
Dim HOST As String = "http://test.com/"
Dim USER_ID As String = "userid"
Dim PASSWORD As String = "password"
Dim FILE_ID As String = "DOC_00000000000000_0000000000"
Dim SPACE_ID As String = "SPACE_00000000000000_0000000000"
Dim FILE_PATH As String = "C:\" & vbTab & "est.txt"
Dim FILE_NAME As String = "test.txt"
Public SEND_CHUNK_SIZE As Long = (1024 * 1024)

Private Sub btnBrowse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse.Click
    Dim openFileDialog As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    Dim dialogResult = openFileDialog.ShowDialog()
    If dialogResult <> dialogResult.OK Then Return
    upload(openFileDialog.FileName)
End Sub

Private Async Sub upload(ByVal filePath As String)
    Dim file As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath)
    Dim readed As Long = 0
    Dim size As Long = 0
    Dim info As New FileInfo(file)
    Dim chunk As Long = 0
    Try
        readed = 0

        Dim filename = Path.GetFileName(file)
        Dim client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
        Dim postData As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
        postData.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("filename", filename))
        postData.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("versionkind ", "1"))
        postData.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("verUp ", "true"))
        postData.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("chunk ", chunk))
        postData.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("chunks ", "0"))
        Dim content As HttpContent = New FormUrlEncodedContent(postData)
        MsgBox(content)
        Dim response = Await client.PostAsync(HOST + "/contentsmanagement/ContentsAdd.json", content)
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()

        chunk = (chunk + 1)            
    Catch e As Exception
        MsgBox(e.Message)
        Return
    End Try
End Sub
```

I am struggling with the VB.Net, but I don't know how to upload it. I'm not very good with VB.Net. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You need to describe your problem in detail. "Here's some code, I don't know what to do" is not an SO question. When you debug the code, stepping through it line by line, does it behave as you expect? If not, how and where does it differ?

Answer (score 0):

I think HttpClient is a bit advanced for your purpose.

I suggest working with WebClient instead. You can use it like this:

```vb
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
client.UploadFile(url, filename)
```

Comment: I know, but the requirement need me to use httpclient